# Preview and Final Render Materials are Different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, fluid-simulation

In my node editor I have the following Materials set for the water which is made with a fluid simulation.

[image]

In the preview window it looks like this (Which is how I want it.)

[image]

Then when I render out the image it looks like this (Not how I want it.)

[image]

Below are my render settings

[image]

[image]

I tried detaching the glass node and I still got the see through look. I tried closing and reopening the project file. I tried changing the camera too incase I messed something up with the lens. I can't seem to figure out what's happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Try setting your Render Samples equal to your Preview Samples.

Comment: Just tried. Still the same outcome.... lol

Answer (score 1):

So I had to make sure that the resolution of the simulation between it's preview and final render were the same

[image]